# UITableView reloaddata and tableHeaderView issue

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I want to display something in the tableHeaderView and a blank table, then download something and reload the tableView and display something different in the tableHeaderView after that. Is there somewhere I can put the code to change the tableHeaderView and these code will be called once the table is loaded each time?
Thanks.

Comment: No need to reloadData of table as you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table Header you can take UILabel, UIView, UIImageView, UITextField, etc. anything you want. Then you just put it in the interface builer and bind it with the controller and whenever you need to update it you can just update without even reloading the tableView.

If you have the data inside the table then you have to do reloadData. But for the data in headerview, no need to do reloadData. Instead of that you can directly assign the value to your headerview as follows.

```
headerLaber.text=@"Header";
headerImageView.image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"image1.png"];
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I found out this solution just after posting this question. The tableView style of doing things make me forget the straight way. lol.

Comment: I tried doing this, but the labels were not updated. Any clue why that would occur?

Comment: @gurooj: Here you can bind it with the interface builder and set the property of Label then it will be updated as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

in the interface builder, you can put a UILabel, or whatever view you want, inside the header of the UITabelView. Just drag the component you want to. I also advice you to create an IBOulet, so you can access it later. After you make something like this:

```
[youTableView reloadData];
```

Then you can update your header:

```
myHeaderLabel.text=@"New info i want to display".
```